# JAVA Http Tunneling: example needed

Tags: java, http, chat, tunneling

I'm programming a chat but i have troubles on finding informations and/or examples regarding the HTTP tunneling. The chat, when initialized, starts his own server thread that manages the incoming messages. That said i need to send strings of data to another client's server via http tunneling. Is that possible ? how can i do that ?

Comment: I recommend you ignore the "tunneling" part when searching, and look for information on how to use the Java HTTP server and client libraries. You could make each chat node be a server and have them connect to each other directly.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Tunelling is an encapsulation of other protocols that use the TCP stack.
For example you could define the messages exchanged for chat among the various endpoints e.g. in XML and then put the XML in the HTTP POST body.
There are plenty of examples of this in the internet.
Just search for REST or Web services (this includes SOAP which is also tunnelled in HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chat example demo web application bundled in activeMQ. You can find it [here](http://activemq.apache.org/web-samples.html).